# Linked list- current vs. current.next when appending

Tags: python, linked-list

Node:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
```

def add() part one:

```
def add(self, newData):
    
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = Node(newData)
        return
  
    current = self.head
```

def add() part  2

Why does this work?

```
    while current.next:
        current = current.next
    
    current.next =  Node(newData)
```

And this doesn't?

```
    while current:
        current = current.next
            
    current = Node(newData)
```

Aren't "current.next" in first one and "current" in second one same?

Comment: In the second one, when the `while` loop exits, `current` is indeed the previous `current.next` but it's just a name, so assigning to it won't actually change the previous `current.next`.

Comment: `while current` only terminates when `current == None`. Then, you're trying to assign to it. However, when you instead do it with `current.next`, you're checking if a node is linked with anything, and if not linking it with a new node at the end of your list.

Comment: The second `if self.head is None:` condition will never be true, since you handled that case before doing `current = self.head`

Comment: Let's simply this. If you `b = 1`, `a = b` and then `a = 3`, does it change `b`? If not, why would you expect `current = something` to change the previous `current.next`? They're two variables that contain the same value, but assigning one doesn't change the other.

Comment: @Barmar  Yeah, true... I don't know how I missed that. As of second `if self.head is None:`, I don't know how that got there, must've copied it twice on accident.

Comment: "Aren't "current.next" in first one and "current" in second one same?" I can't understand why you think they would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between the two loop codes is the last line, where you either assign to `current.next` or to `current`. Those do fundamentally different things.

When you assign to `current.next`, you're modifying an attribute of the `Node` object referenced by `current`. That change happens in place, so you'll see the change through other references (like the chain of nodes earlier in the list). That's what you want to happen.

In the modified version, when you assign to `current`, you're only rebinding the variable name in the local namespace. You're not changing any node! You could compare it to:

```
a = 1
b = a
b = 2
print(a) # still prints 1
```

Here `b` is `current` in the second version of your code. `a` is the `next` attribute of the last node of the list (which was called `current.next` in the working version of the code). Rebinding the local name `b` doesn't change the other reference to the same value.